# Not able to select node for XML using xpath

Tags: java, xpath

I am not able to  select any node using xpath in the following XML. I have used online xpath parser to get node /PartyHierarchyView//HQPDBID but i am not getting the node.Any pointer will be very helpfull. Following is the XML document.

```
<ns1:PartyHierarchyView xmlns:ns1="http://wwwin.cisco.com/it/AtA/ef/AtAEFSchema">
  <ns1:PartyID>52428</ns1:PartyID>  
  <ns2:ParentID xmlns:ns2="http://wwwin.cisco.com/it/AtA/AtASchema">  
    <ns2:Type>HQ</ns2:Type> 
  </ns2:ParentID>  
  <ns3:HQID xmlns:ns3="http://wwwin.cisco.com/it/AtA/AtASchema"> 52428</ns3:HQID>  
  <ns1:HQName> 
    <ns4:Type xmlns:ns4="http://wwwin.cisco.com/it/AtA/AtASchema"> PARTY_TYPE</ns4:Type> 
  </ns1:HQName>  
  <ns1:HQPDBID> 
    <ns6:Identifier xmlns:ns6="http://wwwin.cisco.com/it/AtA/AtASchema"> 2224283</ns6:Identifier>  
    <ns7:Type xmlns:ns7="http://wwwin.cisco.com/it/AtA/AtASchema"> PDB_ID</ns7:Type> 
  </ns1:HQPDBID> 
</ns1:PartyHierarchyView>
```

Comment: Perhaps you should show your code?

Comment: have you properly declared the namespaces in your xpath engine? the xpath you use assumes the `ns1` namespace to be the default namespace or an xpath engine that is not namespace-aware (does such a thing even exist?).